# Problems migrating React to SSR. import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs, server-side-rendering

So, I've been following a YouTube tutorial on how to migrate React to SSR, since I want to get my app in Google's crawler. This is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwyQONeqRXA
And this is the project: https://github.com/MerceneX/BoomMap/tree/development

The difference is I'm using npm and the tutorial dude is useing yarn. Not sure if that makes a difference due to my lack of knowledge on this topic. I setup the server.js and index.js (this is not yet commited to the github due to it not working), and upon running `npm run ssr` which is set to run `node index.js` I get the following error message:

```
npm run ssr

> client@0.1.0 ssr D:\Projects\Webpages\BoomMap\clientTest
> node index.js

D:\Projects\Webpages\BoomMap\clientTest\node_modules\reactstrap\es\Col.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends";
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Module._compile (D:\Projects\Webpages\BoomMap\clientTest\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Projects\Webpages\BoomMap\clientTest\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

The server.js and index.js are the same as the tutorial, but to ball everything in one place, here they are:
**index.js:**

```
require("ignore-styles");

require("@babel/register")({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
});

require("./server");
```

**server.js:**

```
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import App from "./src/App";

const PORT = 3005;

const app = express();

app.use("^/$", (req, res, next) => {
    fs.readFile(path.resolve("./build/index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send("Error reading build");
        }
        return res.send(
            data.replace(
                '<div id="root"></div>',
                `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
            )
        );
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "build")));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App launched on localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

I have no clue what to do here, as the error is coming from a reacstrap library. Conflict of dependencies maybe?

Anyways, if anyone has a better idea on how to get a website to SSR or any other method to get it crawled by Google, I'm very much looking for advice :)

Thanks for reading this, cheers.